# JIRA: Epic issue that can last for multiple versions and "Affect versions"&"Fix versions" fields

Tags: jira, versioning, user-stories, epic

I have a project.
It is a web-site.
The project has just started.
I found reasonable to group all design-related stories into one Epic called "Design"...

**BUT**

...At the moment I started to fill "Design" epic JIRA card I caught myself at being not sure how to proper handle the epic over versions (especially looking on "Affect versions"&"Fix versions" fields).

The problem is:

- from one side this epic could be strictly planned in version 1.0 and finished in this version. In this case the epic should contain only design tasks for version 1.0. The question: how to organize design stories that are beyond version 1.0?? With this approach I cannot put them into this epic. So, where?
- from other side I can place all design specific stories (despite versioning, 'cause some of them are planned to 1.0 release, others are known but planned to further releases) into the same epic. But in this case how to fill "Affect versions" & "Fix versions" fields? How to organize stories inside this long lasting epic?

Personally I feel that the latter option is better but I would like to listen for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the design epics in to smaller themes that will allow easier planning per version. For instance, you could have an epic for the header and that would hold all the stories needed to design and develop the header. I advise against putting everything in one epic. The version needs to show what was released on that date. By having an epic span versions, it will get confusing to see what you released. Here's Jira's definition:

> A version is a set of features and fixes released together as a single update to your product. Assigning issues to versions helps you plan the order in which new features (stories) for your product will be released to your customers.